# R `scales::comma` works yet `scales::comma()` does not - why?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

When I am using a function in a package I can often write it in the form `function()` or just `function` without parenthesis. This doesn't seem to be the case with `scales::comma`. Why does line 7 work below, yet line 8 does not.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(n = n * 1000) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl, n)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +  # line 7
  # scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma()) +  # line 8
  geom_line()
```

---

*LINE 8 Error*

```
Error in number(x = x, accuracy = accuracy, scale = scale, prefix = prefix,  : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is taken from the help page of `scale_y_continuous` concerning the input parameter `labels`:

**labels**  One of:

- NULL for no labels
- waiver() for the default labels computed by the transformation object
- A character vector giving labels (must be same length as breaks)
- A **function** that takes the breaks as input and returns labels as output

The last one is the important one in this case.
Labels expects a function which `scales::comma` is. `scales::comma()` on the other hand is what that function returns but is not a function anymore.